# How do we translate 这就要求我们做好企业管理，防备出现轰轰烈烈开张，随即偃旗息鼓的局面?

Tags: translation

> 在众多的连锁药店当中，有企业自身创建的，也有许多加盟的。由于数量增长过快，出现[鱼目混珠](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%B1%BC%E7%9B%AE%E6%B7%B7%E7%8F%A0)的现象也[在所难免](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%9C%A8%E6%89%80%E9%9A%BE%E5%85%8D)，**这就要求我们做好企业管理，防备出现轰轰烈烈开张，随即偃旗息鼓的局面**。
> <sub>HSK6 Standard Course 6上 workbook, chapter 18, listening ([original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SLPT.jpg))</sub>

I'm having trouble understanding precisely what this says, especially the part in bold.  I think the basic idea is clear: there are many pharmacies around, so we need to pay attention to management.  But I'm unclear about the logic here, and also unclear on how [开张](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%BC%80%E5%BC%A0) = "to open a business" and [局面](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%B1%80%E9%9D%A2) = "situation" are being used in the last part.

> *My translation*: Among the many chain pharmacies, some companies are self-established, whereas others are unionized.  Due to the overly rapid increase, it is hard to avoid fakes.  **This demands that we carefully manage our business, to guard against large-scale business openings, and soon after a give-in situation.**

**Question**: How do we translate 这就要求我们做好企业管理，防备出现轰轰烈烈开张，随即偃旗息鼓的局面?

---

In case it helps, here are some automatic translations:

> *Google Translate*: Among the many chain pharmacies, some have been established by enterprises themselves, and many have joined. Due to the rapid growth of the number, the phenomenon of fish-eyes mixing is inevitable. **This requires us to do a good job in corporate management and guard against a vigorous opening, and then the situation will die down.**
>
> *Bing Translate*: Among the many drugstores chain, there are enterprises created by themselves, but also many to join. Because the number of growth is too fast, the phenomenon of fish mixed beads is inevitable, **which requires us to do a good job of enterprise management, prepared for the emergence of a roaring opening, and then the situation**.
>
> *Baidu Translate*: Among the many chain pharmacies, there are enterprises created by themselves and many joined in. Due to the rapid growth of the number, it is inevitable that fish eyes mixed with pearls, **which requires us to do a good job in enterprise management to prevent the vigorous opening and then stop**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

轰轰烈烈 - Something that attracts a huge amount of attention from the public. In here, that something is the opening of a new business (开张)

偃旗息鼓 - At the finish of a road/side-walk show, the group flag is taken down and the drum is muted. Here, it implies the business is finished (ceases to operate).

这就要求我们做好企业管理，防备出现轰轰烈烈开张，随即偃旗息鼓的局面.

**This requires/demands us to do a good job in enterprise management to prevent the situation that a business ceases to operate soon/shortly after the eye-popping/catching opening.**

Answer (score 2):

这就 - It just

要求 - requires

我们做好企业管理， - we do a good job in business management

防备 - to prevent

出现 - occur

轰轰烈烈开张 -  grand open in high profile

随即 - then immediately

偃旗息鼓 - cease operation

的局面 - the situation of

> 这就要求我们做好企业管理，防备出现轰轰烈烈开张，随即偃旗息鼓的局面

It just requires we do a good job in business management, to prevent the situation of "(companies) grand open in high profile, and then cease operation shortly after" to occur

开张(v) = 'grand open'; (a business) start operating

偃旗息鼓 (put away the flags and stop the drums) is a sign of an army has stopped its military operation. The term is often used as a metaphor for 'cease operation'

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing 我们 refers to the government in some form. An official is speaking.

由于数量增长过快，
Because the number (of franchises) grew too fast,

出现鱼目混珠的现象也在所难免，
it is almost unavoidable to prevent the sale of fake or imitation products,

这就要求我们做好企业管理，
this requires us to maintain a strict business mangement policy,

防备出现轰轰烈烈开张，
to guard against companies starting with a big bang,

随即偃旗息鼓的局面。
only to, immediately following, fizzle out like a damp squib.

The government does not want to encourage this practice, but wants companies which endure.